# NullPointerException when implementing Android MediaRecorder

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-mediarecorder

I'm new to Android dev, and I've been struggling for days to figure out why I'm getting a NPE when trying to run my MediaRecorder code. All the app is doing is recording a sound from the device, and storing it locally on the device. I imagine it's something simple, but I have yet to find a solution. Maybe you guys could help? Code below:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.util.Log;


public class AudioRecorder {

private static final String LOG_TAG = "AudioRecordTest";
private static String mFileName = null;
private File mFile = null;
private static MediaRecorder mRecorder;
private static MediaPlayer   mPlayer;
public static boolean recordStart;
public static boolean playStart;

public void onRecord(boolean start) {
   if(!playStart){
        if (start) {
            startRecording();
            recordStart = true;
        } else {
            stopRecording();
            recordStart=false;
        }
   }else{
       //do nothing - something is currently being played, you need to stop it first
   }

}

public void onPlay(boolean start) {
    if(!recordStart && mFile != null){
        if (start) {
            startPlaying();
            playStart = true;
        } else {
            stopPlaying();
            playStart = false;
        }
    } else {
        //do nothing - something is being recorded, you need to stop it first
    }

}

public void startPlaying() {
    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        mPlayer.setDataSource(mFile.getAbsolutePath());
        mPlayer.prepare();
        mPlayer.start();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }
    playStart = true;
}

public void stopPlaying() {
    mPlayer.release();
    mPlayer = null;
    playStart = false;
}

public void startRecording() {
    mRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
    mRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mRecorder.setOutputFile(this.mFile.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        mRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "prepare() failed");
    }

    mRecorder.start();
    recordStart = true;
}

public void stopRecording() {
    mRecorder.stop();
    mRecorder.release();
    mRecorder = null;
    recordStart = false;
}
}
```

And here is the code for the buttons that play/stop/record:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;

public class AudioRecorderActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private AudioRecorder mRecorder = new AudioRecorder();
    private AudioPlayer mPlayer = new AudioPlayer();
    private View mPlayButton;
    private View mStopButton;
    private View mRecordButton;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    mPlayButton = findViewById(R.id.play_button);
    mPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            mRecorder.onPlay(true);
        }
    });

    mRecordButton = findViewById(R.id.record_button);
    mRecordButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            mRecorder.onRecord(true);
        }
    });

    mStopButton = findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
    mStopButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (AudioRecorder.playStart == true){
                mRecorder.stopPlaying();
            } else if (AudioRecorder.recordStart == true){
                mRecorder.stopRecording();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

The error is very clearly in my startRecording() method but I can't see what I've done wrong:

```
10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at com.lcc.w.AudioRecorder.startRecording(AudioRecorder.java:74)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at com.lcc.w.AudioRecorder.onRecord(AudioRecorder.java:24)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at com.lcc.w.AudioRecorderActivity$2.onClick(AudioRecorderActivity.java:36)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4963)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
    10-05 21:55:51.620: E/AndroidRuntime(4172):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The NPE is coming from 'com.lcc.w.AudioRecorder' when running method 'onRecord'.  Can you post line 24 from the 'com.lcc.w.AudioRecorder' class?

Comment: Hi @Prmths, yeah the first chunk of code is the AudioRecord class. Line 24 is under the onRecord method, it says startRecording(), which is a method later on in the class.

Comment: The source the exception is at `AudioRecorder.java:74`.

Comment: Yep, and this is line 74:         mRecorder.setOutputFile(this.mFile.getAbsolutePath());

(I can't figure out how to include line numbers for the code in my code chunks on here!)

Comment: I don't know that either, but nevermind. I already thought that this line causes trouble. `mFile` is never set anythere. Therefore it stays `null`. Btw: you're checking the value of `mFile` in `onPlay` but not in `onRecord`.

Comment: Ah yes, that did make the NPE go away! Duh. Thanks, @Tom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Stacktrace shows that the exception occurs on line `74` in the class `AudioRecorder`.
You said that it is this line:

```
mRecorder.setOutputFile(this.mFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

The problem here is, that it calls the method `getAbsolutePath()` on the null object `mFile`. This variable is `null`, because it was initialised with null here `private File mFile = null;` and never "filled" the a real `File` object.

I asume you just forgot to do that.

And btw you're checking the current value of `mFile` in the method `onPlay()`

```
public void onPlay (boolean start) {
    if (!recordStart && mFile != null) {
        //..
    }
    //...
}
```

but not in method `onRecord()`. You could consider doing that there as well.

Comment: As predicted, it was something that simple! Thanks for the answer.